# Connect MongoDB/MySQL using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, database

how to connect database with javascript?

mongodb with some example? or mysql?

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]]` `[/[database][?options]]
```

performance of this databese which can be used in a tcp server?:

```
~/$ ./mongod
```

> db.adminCommand({movePrimary:, to:})

```
  //enable sharding on the database, and move it to the shard01
```

> use test1 //new database
>   db.adminCommand({enablesharding : "test1"})
>   db.adminCommand({movePrimary : "test1", to : "shard01" })
>   //This will affect new collections on the test1 db
>   //enable sharding on the database, and move it to the shard01
>   use test1 //new database
>   db.adminCommand({enablesharding : "test1"})
>   db.adminCommand({movePrimary : "test1", to : "shard01" })
>   //This will affect new collections on the test1 db

Answer (score 0):

I realize you may have figured this out by now, but check this link out:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api

You should be able to access MongoDB via ajax calls in Javascript and receive JSON objects as your response.